# Export all product from dataflow- profile in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, export, dataflow

I want to export all product from with the help of dataflow profile in Magento.

In my site I have 3000+ products. When I export product data from dataflow profile, it opens the new window and after 1 or 2 seconds it is showing "500 Internal error".

So I can't export my products.

Please help me, how to export my all products from dataflow? And also, are there any alternative solutions?

Comment: help to the link:-http://lero9.co.nz/magento-tips/how-to-export-your-magento-product-database-using-using-magentos-importexport-dataflow-profiles/

Comment: I have tried this process again  but when click on "run profile", after 2 minute it showing  "500 Internal error" because it taking more time.

Comment: Uncomment the `#ini_set(‘display_errors’, 1);` in your `index.php` so you can see what's wrong. Also take a look at these hints: http://techjam.gr/2012/magento/solve-magento-500-internal-server-errors/

Answer (score 0):

You can use export module feature.

Admin panel -> system -> import/export -> export and select 
Entity Type as product select the product which is commom for all the product and then select continue, you can export all the product.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively explicitly you can export products.
Here it is.

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$collection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
$fopen = fopen('exportProducts.csv', 'w');
$csvHeader = array("id","sku", "name", "price","description","categories","image_url");
fputcsv( $fopen , $csvHeader,",");
foreach ($collection as $product){
        $id = $product->getId();
        $sku = $product->getSku();
        $name = $product->getName();
        $description = $product->getDescription();      
        $price = $product->getPrice();      
        $imageurl  = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl( $product->getImage() );           
        $category = $product->getCategoryIds();     
        unset($catName);
        $catName = array();
        for($j=0;$jload($category[$j])->getName();
        }
        $catname = implode(",",$catName);           
        fputcsv($fp, array($id, $sku, $name, $price, $description, $catname,$imageurl ), ",");
}
fclose($fopen );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$data=array();
$data['entity'] = 'catalog_product';
$data['file_format'] = 'csv';
$data['form_key'] =Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); 
$data['export_filter']=array();

$model = Mage::getModel('importexport/export');
$model->setData($data);

$model->export();
$model->getContentType();

?>
```

you use this script to export all product
it will generate csv file in var importexport folder